# SpecFlow+ config file transformation alternatives in .net core?

Tags: specflow

I'm wanting to run some SpecFlow+ tests with a bunch of config settings for a particular environment, then have the option of running the same tests against a different bunch of settings for a different environment.

With SpecFlow+ in .net framework this could be achieved by transforming the `App.config` file with environment specific `.srprofile` files. You could then hook up a `.runsettings` file to the `.srprofile` file and seamlessly change the environment you want to run your tests on by changing the test run settings in Visual Studio.

Is there an equivalent solution in .net core?

The only workaround I can think of is to use a different build configuration for each environment and then use `#if DEBUG` style preprocessor directives in code. That could then load a specific appsettings.json file or point to specific Azure App Configuration settings. I could then set the BuildConfiguration in my pipeline when running the tests.

Comment: Would Environment Variables work for you? We use them in this example: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/blob/master/SeleniumWebTest/TestApplication.UiTests/Default.srprofile#L17

Comment: I believe that example requires the use of tags to extract the environment variables (?). I would prefer not to add tags to all my tests if I wanted to run an entire test suite pointed at different config settings. The flexibility I was after was the possibility of running tests for multiple browsers on an environment (which your suggestion does address), on multiple environments (e.g. Test, Sandbox, Live) and with the option of running on specific instances within those environments (e.g. Test 1, Test 2 etc). All the while being able to switch between these instances easily when debugging.

Comment: Ok, multiple different browsers are always used, and depending on the configuration, you test against one to many environments. Probably configured by an URL. Is this your case? Then I can create an appropriate example for this for you.

Comment: Yep that's it, and the config may have other details such as API endpoint URL's, database connection strings, usernames etc. I've been experimenting with Azure App Configuration which allows me to pull out a bunch of settings based on a label (e.g. test) which I can then feed into my application via an environment setting. This could be set in the pipeline for different targets. Only downside is it's not ideal for debugging and requires either a manual code change or manual environment variable value change.

Comment: Multiple build configurations also works and is nice for debugging, but I don't want to be reliant on separate artifacts for each environment if I want to run a release. I would prefer to be able to feed in a setting to the same artifact to run on multiple environments if needed. Interested to see your example if you have something else in mind....

Comment: What you are describing is the usecase of the Target of the SpecFlow+ Runner. With combination of some deploymentsteps your requirements should be possible. The posted example uses both, but in a little different way. I hope I find some time in the next days, to create an example, that meets your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new example for your use case. You can find it at https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/MultipleBrowserAgainstDifferentEnvironments

You can define in the [Default.srProfile](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/blob/master/MultipleBrowserAgainstDifferentEnvironments/TestApplication.UiTests/Default.srprofile) which browser is used for which environment.
The base URL is configured via the `__BaseUrl` environment.

This is an example to use Firefox with google.com as base address.

```xml
<Target name="Firefox-COM">
  <DeploymentTransformationSteps>
     <EnvironmentVariable variable="Test_Browser" value="Firefox" />
     <EnvironmentVariable variable="__BaseUrl" value="https://www.google.com" />
  </DeploymentTransformationSteps>
</Target>
```

If you need more values to configure, you can simply add new environment variables and get their value with a simple `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` (https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/blob/master/MultipleBrowserAgainstDifferentEnvironments/TestApplication.UiTests/Drivers/ConfigurationDriver.cs#L9).

You can also write multiple different `srProfile`- files and with different [runsettings files](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-runner/en/latest/Installation/Configuring-SpecFlowPlus-Runner-Visual-Studio-Test-Explorer-Integration.html#specflow-runner-settings) you can have different settings if you are running the tests locally or in your CI pipeline.

If the environment variables are not enough or are getting too much to handle, I would suggest using only one environment variable, where you store a filename.
In your bindings you can then use this filename to read out it.

I hope this example helps you to achieve your requirements.

---

Full disclosure: I am a developer on SpecFlow & SpecFlow+

Comment: Many thanks for this. I'll need to carve out some time to go through it in detail but I'll make sure to report back.